# Automating company information search on Google (merger acquisitions) using NLP & ML

Tags: python, machine-learning, beautifulsoup, nlp

So Im trying to find out if a company has been acquired by another company or not. Lets say I search for halli labs and want to know whether its been acquired or not. If yes then I need to know the parent company name. My approach is to google search "Halli labs parent company". Then Ive scraped all the text on the first page, all the corresponding links, date etc. Then I can run pos tag, generate bigrams, trigrams etc and feed it to some algorithm to find if the text is about acquisition, if yes then pull out the company name.

The problem now is that, the name of the companies are getting tagged as "PERSON", is there a way I can resolve this ?

Also is my approach good enough ? Because thats basically how a human would find whether a company has been acquired or not ?

```
nltk.ne_chunk(nltk.pos_tag(nltk.tokenize.word_tokenize("Google has acquired Halli Labs, a four-month old start-up out of Bengaluru that is developing artificial intelligence and machine learning")))
```

Comment: You could try training an NER model on your own dataset. The default NER taggers will be of limited use for your purpose since they have been trained using their own dataset.
This is a good tutorial that you can follow:
https://blog.sicara.com/train-ner-model-with-nltk-stanford-tagger-english-french-german-6d90573a9486

Your approach right now is very vague. It would be helpful if you could explain your approach in more details.

Answer (score 0):

You can always train your own NER models with your data set. **Spacy** could be a great tool for this. But NER prediction models are generally composed of deep neural networks, which need a lot of training data which can be difficult to get. So, instead of training a model from scratch, it might be better to update a existing basic NER model with training data where the basic model is failing.Then only providing the correct annotations for those false positive examples, the model should perform better. Spacy has an API to do this, read this [tutorial](https://spacy.io/usage/training#section-ner).

Note that on line 35, code is to be edited to load a basic 'en' model instead of 'blank' model. Also, read the section **"Training an additional entity type"** in the same page.